# Vim doesn't seem to load syntax from package installed in .vim/pack folder

Tags: macos, vim, rust

I'm trying to setup Rust support in Vim. I have got:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
```

...running on:

```
x86_64-apple-darwin (darwin17)
```

I've cloned the `rust-lang/rust.vim` repo into `~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim`, and then installed Syntastic the same way. After reading several websites about the Vim8 package system, I assumed that there's no need for "registering" the plugins in the `vimrc`.

Then I started to write code, but noticed that the `match` keyword isn't highlighted at all. Also, there's `no help for rust-syntastic` and `no help for syntastic-checkers`, even though there should be.

I've checked `:scriptnames`, and these are the loaded components for `rust.vim` and `syntastic`:

```
22: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/plugin/cargo.vim
23: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/plugin/rust.vim
24: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/ftdetect/rust.vim
25: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim
26: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/balloons.vim
27: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/checker.vim
28: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/cursor.vim
29: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/highlighting.vim
30: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/loclist.vim
31: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/modemap.vim
32: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/notifiers.vim
33: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim
34: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/signs.vim
35: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim
36: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/syntastic/autoload/syntastic/util.vim
```

Then I tried removing `rust.vim` from the `~/.vim/pack/plugins/start` directory, and the syntax highlighting stayed the same (everything highlighted except for `match` and lifetimes), so I assume that either:

1. Syntax didn't load (and I'm required to do additional configuring of the plugins).
2. The highlighting of `match` is conditional, and the condition isn't for some reason fulfilled.
3. There's a problem with my installation of Rust and Cargo.

My `vimrc` file contains:

```
set nocompatible

syntax enable
filetype plugin indent on

colorscheme Tomorrow-Night

set colorcolumn=100
set number

set incsearch
set showmatch

set ignorecase
set smartcase

set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e

let mapleader=","


" Moving around

map <leader>e $
map <leader>a 0
map <leader>t H
map <leader>d L

nmap j gj
nmap k gk
nmap m h


" Last edit position

augroup last_edit
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPost *
       \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
       \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
       \ endif
augroup END
```

So my question reads:
**Did I install these plugins incorrectly, or is it a flaw of their own?**

Comment: Maybe you should also tell us which platform you are on?

Comment: @hxpax Done, platform added (darwin17).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your installation. Having no help is natural, you have to generate the tags after installing new docs with `:helptags ALL`. How did you edit a new file? Is the filetype correct? Check with `:set ft`

Comment: @sidyll Ok, I've generated the helptags, checked the filetype, and it's indeed Rust. The only keyword that doesn't get highlighted is `match`. I find that rather strange, and since I haven't found the `~/.vim/pack/.../syntax/rust.vim` file in `scriptnames`, I suspect it isn't loaded, but I don't know whether or not it should load.